# Callback for ConnectivityManager not working in BlueStacks 5 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluestacks, android-connectivitymanager

In order to get notified when the device connects/disconnects from internet, I took the following approach:

```java
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = activity.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);

        ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                try {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        tvNoInternet.animate().alpha(0f).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                MiscellaneousUtils.hideView(tvNoInternet, View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                        behaviour.onConnected();
                        // behaviour is an interface named NetworkConnectionBehaviour (check the following snippet for its implementation)
                    });
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLost(@NonNull Network network) {
                super.onLost(network);
                try {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        if (isInternetConnected(activity)) {
                            // check internet connection status because onLost() is called
                            // after onAvailable() when the device automatically switches
                            // internet connection from cellular to wifi
                            return;
                        }
                        tvNoInternet.animate().alpha(1f).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                                MiscellaneousUtils.showView(tvNoInternet);
                            }
                        });
                        behaviour.onDisconnected();
                    });
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        try {
            NetworkRequest networkRequest = getNetworkRequest(); 
            // implementation of getNetworkRequest() is added in next snippet
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Unexpected interruption! please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Interface NetowrkConnectionBehaviour:

```java
    public interface NetworkConnectionBehaviour {
        void onConnected();

        void onDisconnected();
    }
```

Implementation of `getNetworkRequest()`:

```java
    public static NetworkRequest getNetworkRequest() {
        return new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                .build();
    }
```

This approach is working in all physical devices and emulator of android studio.

However, if someone runs the app on Bluestacks 5 emulator, the callbacks of ConnectivityManager aren't called at all. And it does not produce any exception either.

Am I missing something here? Is there a different way to use ConnectivityManager for BlueStacks?

NOTE: It shows same behaviour for gameloop emulator too.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)` and `addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)`? Maybe the emulator considers its internet connection to not be one of transport types `TRANSPORT_WIFI` or `TRANSPORT_CELLULAR`. The capability `NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET` should still ensure that the connection is working and has access to the internet no matter what the transport type is.

Comment: also, adding `.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)` also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to remove transport types: `TRANSPORT_WIFI` and `TRANSPORT_CELLULAR` since the BlueStacks 5 Emulator does not recognize its connection to be one of those transport types.

The capability `NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET` will ensure that the connection is working and has access to the internet as per [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET):

> Indicates that this network should be able to reach the internet.

The code for the `NetworkRequest` now should be as follows:

```java
public static NetworkRequest getNetworkRequest() {
    return new NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get notified when the device connects/disconnects from internet, It's better to use `registerDefaultNetworkCallback` instead of just `registerNetworkCallback`.
The "default network" means application's default network used for internet connection. as per docs.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager

Try

```
connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
```

And you can use callback as you defined in the question.

AND also, if you want to check it's connected, you should check both `NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET` AND `NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED`.
So I used connectivity check like below.

```
val caps = mConnectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
if (caps.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) &&
            caps.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)) {
    // connected
}
```